# Literature on the hyperelliptic involution

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I'm currently trying to familiarize myself with reducible Jacobians of hyperelliptic curves. A construction which I recently saw in a paper was the quotient $C/\tau$ of a curve $C$ of genus $2$ by a non-hyperelliptic involution $\tau$.

I can get the general idea, but the details of the construction and the following proofs escape me. Almost all of the literature seems to assume a familiarity with properties of such involutions and quotients, but they don't show up at all in the books I read on elliptic curves, abelian varieties and functions fields (there is, as far as I know, very few explicit introductory literature on hyperelliptic curves).

Can someone recommend a good review or some book source which devotes not only two lines to involutions of curves? The genus does not have to be $2$, in fact a more general exposition would be preferable.

Thank you in advance, I would appreciate any guidance and hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=JuY5tsWAHoUC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=%22hyperelliptic%20involution%22&source=bl&ots=upEMP23xmw&sig=G6kLlwsUPENl2oXvh8FSEEsveRs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3N7kT5_cDOb40gHa9qX6CQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22hyperelliptic%20involution%22&f=false), [this book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=UQFMjUCaQ7kC&pg=PA437&lpg=PA437&dq=%22hyperelliptic%20involution%22&source=bl&ots=n_eTggF3wG&sig=ptNZSNMa90nRnpha21T5QeGLs7o&hl=en&sa=X&ei=feDkT6fiEuqJ0QGenODhCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22hyperelliptic%20involution%22&f=false), and [these notes](http://www.scribd.com/doc/36440958/141/Hyperelliptic-involution) contain some exposition on hyperelliptic involutions.

Comment: Thank you very much, that should get me started! Putting those three references together will probably enable me to read papers and work the rest out myself.